# Error when trying to display value using v-for in vue

Tags: php, vue.js, laravel-blade

I have some trouble with understanding an error I am receiving using vue.js and hope that someone can help me out here. I believe that it is a silly mistake but I am unable to spot it.

I am receiving this error here: Use of undefined constant providers - assumed 'providers'. I am using laravel and blade here. I receive this error in the browser. I assume that it has something to do with the way I am trying to display the providers object using v-for loop in vue.js and since I am a beginner, I am probably making a mistake here. Here is my code:

***Component:***

```
Vue.component('filter-section', {
   template: "#filter-template",
   props: ['providers']
});

// create a root instance
new Vue({
   el: '#home-filter-result'
});
```

***Filter-blade.php***

```
<div id="home-filter-result">
  <filter-section v-for="item in providers" :providers='{!! $providers !!}'>
  </filter-section>
  <template id="filter-template">
    {{ item }}  
  </template>
</div>
```

Providers is an object in this format:

providers : 
Array[20]
0:Object

value1: '1'

value2: '2'

value3: '3'

Comment: Try to pass providers like that `:providers='$providers'`

Comment: Also, don't you need to escape the Vue variables with blade: `@{{ item }}` to prevent blade from seeing the braces?

Comment: @Mark_M that certainly solved my browser error, thanks! Blade did indeed see the braces and raised the error.